# What is the authenticity of the hadith on not entering the dwellings of the punished nations?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

i want to ask a question about a hadith,
there is a hadith "Do not pass through the dwelling place of those who wronged themselves without crying….”
i want to ask authenticity of this hadees, is this hadees present in any book like Bukhari or Muslim ?

Answer (score 1):

The Hadith is authentic & it is in sahih-al-Bukhari:

> Allah's Messenger () said, "Do not enter the ruined dwellings of those
> who were unjust to themselves unless (you enter) weeping, lest you
> should suffer the same punishment as was inflicted upon them."
>
> [[Sahih Bukhari 3381]](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3381)